# Insert row for each integer between 0 and <value> without cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a source table with id and count.

```
id count
a     5
b     2
c     31
```

I need to populate a destination table with each integer up to the count for each id.

```
id value
a     1
a     2
a     3
a     4
a     5
b     1
b     2
c     1
c     2
etc...
```

My current solution is like so:

```
INSERT INTO destination (id,value)
    source.id
    sequence.number
FROM 
(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS sequence(number)
INNER JOIN 
source ON sequence.number <= source.count
```

This solution has an upper limit and is plain lame. Is there anyway to replace the sequence with a set of all integers? Or another solution that does not use looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
 WITH r AS (
    SELECT id, count, 1 AS n FROM SourceTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, count, n+1 FROM r WHERE n<count
)
SELECT id,n FROM r
order by id,n
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: No tricks, set/calculation based and only produces integers up to the value required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not set of all integers in SQL Server. However, using a little trickery, you can easily generate such a set:

```
select N from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS N 
    from sys.all_objects t1, sys.all_objects t2
) AS numbers
where N between 1 and 1000000
```

will generate a set of all numbers from 1 through 1000000. If you need more than a few million numbers, add sys.all_objects to the cross join a third time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many examples in this page:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID VARCHAR(1), counter INT)

INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'a', 5
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'b', 3
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'c', 31



;WITH cte (ID, counter) AS (

    SELECT id, 1
    FROM @table 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.counter +1
    FROM cte AS c
    INNER JOIN @table AS t
        ON t.id = c.id
    WHERE c.counter + 1 <= t.counter

)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID, Counter
```